# How to avoid strcpy_s buffer too small

Tags: c++, c, char

I need to copy `std::string data` into a char array.  The length of my string is variable but the length of my char array is fixed.

```
const int SIZE = 5;

char name[SIZE];
std::string data = "1234567890";

strcpy_s(name, 5, data.c_str()); //causes a buffer is too small assertion
strcpy_s(name, 11, data.c_str());//copies fine (length of data plus null)
strcpy_s(name, sizeof(data), data.c_str()); // copies fine
```

How can I copy only the length of the array safely each time? Without getting the assert and without causing a buffer over run.

Should I do it like this each time?

```
std::string toCopy = data.substr(0,SIZE-1);
strcpy_s(name, toCopy.c_str());
```

Comment: If this is C++11, you can just use the string's buffer.

Comment: yes its C++ll.  Can you give me an example of what you mean??

Comment: if you mean "mstrcpy_s(name, data.c_str());" this gives me the assert error which I want to avoid.

Comment: Just do `s2 = s1;` (or a substring as needed) instead of working with C strings. When you need the character pointer, use `&s2[0]` for one that's modifiable until just before the final null terminator or `c_str()` for a non-modifiable one.

Answer (score 9):

Use [strncpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx) with `_TRUNCATE`

For instance:

```
strncpy_s(name, data.c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
```

will copy as much as it can to fill the `name` buffer while still taking null termination into account (unlike the traditional strncpy).

Answer (score 3):

The following returns an ERANGE result because you must have room for the terminating NULL character.  Variable 'data' holds 10 elements.  When strcpy_s reaches the constraint '5' it fails to find a terminating NULL and returns ERANGE.

strcpy_s(name, 5, data.c_str());

[Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx)

> The strcpy_s function copies the contents in the address of strSource,
>   including the terminating null character, to the location that's
>   specified by strDestination. The destination string must be large
>   enough to hold the source string and its terminating null character.
>   The behavior of strcpy_s is undefined if the source and destination
>   strings overlap.

**Alternative Approach**

```
  string data = "0123456789";
  int SIZE = 5;
  char name[SIZE];

  size_t length = data.copy( name, 0, 5 );
  buffer[ length ] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I had enough space for the string, but was not copying the `nullchar`. Really weird behavior, and definitely a weird error message.